# Can't get a Navigation item with CalendarKit

Tags: calendarkit

I've tried to get it to work like so:

```swift
class CalendarViewController: DayViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "CalendarKit Demo"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Dark",
                                                            style: .done,
                                                            target: self,
                                                            action: #selector(changeStyle))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Change Date",
                                                           style: .plain,
                                                           target: self,
                                                           action: #selector(presentDatePicker))
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        dayView.autoScrollToFirstEvent = true
        reloadData()
    }

    @objc func changeStyle() {
        print("clicked change style")
    }

    @objc func presentDatePicker() {
      print("clicked date picker")
    }

    override func eventsForDate(_ date: Date) -> [EventDescriptor] {
        let models = [Happening(startDate: Date(), endDate: Date(timeInterval: 3600, since: Date()), title: "Test Event", location: "on mother earth")]

      var events = [Event]()

      for model in models {
          let event = Event()
          event.startDate = model.startDate
          event.endDate = model.endDate
          let info = [model.title, model.location]
          event.text = info.reduce("", {$0 + $1 + "\n"})
          events.append(event)
      }
      return events
    }
}

struct Happening {
    let startDate: Date
    let endDate: Date
    let title: String
    let location: String

    init (startDate: Date, endDate: Date, title: String, location: String) {
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.endDate = endDate
        self.title = title
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

Calendar shows up but I'm neither getting a title nor navigation items.
Looks like this for me:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?
Many thanks for your help!

Question on the side:
Didn't yet figure out how (or if possible at all) to work with it in interface builder, to e.g. add a custom navigation element at the top when integrating it into another app. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

starting from the last question: the Interface Builder is not currently supported. I recommend creating your `CalendarController` in code. Some features might work with the Interface Builder, although their support is not guaranteed.

The missing link is that the `CalendarController` is not embedded inside an instance of the `UINavigationController`. You can do so in your `AppDelegate.swift` or `SceneDelegate.swift` file:

```
import UIKit
import CalendarKit

@UIApplicationMain
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let dayViewController = CalendarViewController() // Create a view controller
    // Now create a NavigationController with CalendarController embedded inside
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dayViewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController

    return true
  }
}
```

Let me know, if this helps you integrate the CalendarKit. Also, I'd appreciate having a reproducible test project, so that I could investigate the problem myself.